# Loading native dll's at runtime

Tags: c#

Let’s say I have an extern method that is used to calculate the square root of a number.
Like:

```
using System;
public static class Program 
{
    Public static extern double Sqrt(double x);

    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Sqrt(64));
    }
}
```

For the extern method to work, I will have to load a DLL which is usually done by using `DllImport`.
But let’s say I want to load the DLL at runtime by calling a method, like in Java:

```
System.load(“Path to DLL”);
```

Can this be done in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import the same `LoadLibrary` that you're accustomed to using.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lib);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern void FreeLibrary(IntPtr module);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr module, string proc);
```

Example use (you should add error handling):

```
delegate int MyDelegate(int n, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string s);

var module = LoadLibrary("Foo.dll");
var method = GetProcAddress(module, "doSomething");
var doSomething = (MyDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(method, typeof(MyDelegate));
var result = doSomething(2, "Hello world!"); 
FreeLibrary(module);
```

See [this article](https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/17244/dynamic-loading-and-unloading-of-unmanaged-dlls)

Comment: If `doSomething` have arguments of string type or other non-primitive types, I will need to marshal such an arguments manually, am I right? And there is no way to achieve automatic marshaling with help of attributes or something similar as we can do for `DllImport`.

Comment: Pretty sure it's the same, you'd just set the `MarshalAs` attribute on the parameters in declaration of `MyDelegate`.